# Switching between RDP sessions on OS X El Capital

Tags: macos, keyboard, remote-desktop, shortcut

OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

I use Microsoft Remote Desktop 8.0.26

and many times open multiple sessions

The only way to switch these sessions i see is by clicking using mouse and i can't find any keyboard shortcuts to switch between multiple session

Is there any way to switch between sessions?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same key command as any Mac app…   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>  
which cycles through all open windows [in RDP's case, that also includes the 'picker'.]
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>  will reverse the direction.

<kbd>`</kbd>  seems to move around depending on which nationality keyboard you have, on a UK keyboard it's left of  <kbd>z</kbd> .

<sup>Perhaps others could add in the location for other keyboard layouts…</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a solution to a similar problem (I was looking for exactly the same thing - to be able to switch to Remote session, instead of the main window of MS Remote Desktop and double clicking the session of interest), with the only difference being, I only use 1 session at a time (unlike the OP who uses multiple sessions simultaneously.

Unfortunately, @Tetsujin's answer hasn't helped me. What did help me was to Turn ON the option named "Pin to Menu Bar"

[image: Microsoft Remote Desktop - Pin to Menu Bar]